number of sign changes of a band-limited function
Is there a way to bound the number of sign changes of a (continuous) band-limited function $f(x)$ in an interval $x\in[a,b]$?
For example, for finite dimensional vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, if its cosine transform $\hat{x}$ satisfies $\hat{x}[i]=0$ for $2\leq i\leq n$, because then the vector is DC and a cosine function. Perhaps there are identities that help see something similar if $\hat{x}[i]=0$ for $k\leq i\leq n$ for some $1\leq k< n$, but I'm not sure how to do that.
I am looking for a general result that covers also functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and not vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but anything relevant is interesting.
I have seen in the literature all kinds of referencing to Paley-Wiener theorem and Titchmarsh's theorem, but I couldn't find anything explicit and I wasn't able to use Paley-Wiener to obtain this bound.
Thanks so much!

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but $\cos(\theta_i x)$ are linearly independent on any $[a,b]$, no matter how close the $\theta_i$ are, so you can always find a set $S$ of $n$ points in $[a,b]$ so that their restriction is also linearly independent, and consequently is a basis for this $n$-dimensional space. Then just alternate between assigning $1$ and $-1$ to elements of $S$ and this function is in the span, so by taking that linear combination of the $\cos(\theta_i x)$ you get a function with at least $n-1$ sign changes on $[a,b]$.
